# Finding neighboring vectors using inner product

Tags: inner-products

I am trying to find a specific vector space as below. $v_0$ and $v_k$ are $n$-dimensional vectors, and for a given $v_0$ and $\theta$, the vector space is defined as: 
$V(v_0) = \{ v_k \in \mathcal{R}^n \, | \, <v_0,v_k> = |v_0||v_k|\cos(\theta) = 1 \}$.

How do I find the vector space $V(v_0)$? Can I somehow parameterize it in terms of $v_0$? I am trying to create a finite number of $v_k \in V(v_0)$ in Matlab. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could this work?

Assuming $|v_0| \cdot \cos \theta > 0$,
\begin{align}
&|v_0| \cdot |v_k| \cos \theta = 1 \\
\iff |v_k| &= \frac{1}{|v_0| \cos \theta} \\
\iff \sqrt{v_{k1}^2 + v_{k2}^2 + ... + v_{kn}^2} &= \frac{1}{|v_0| \cos \theta} \\
\iff v_{kn}^2 &= \frac{1}{|v_0|^2 \cos^2 \theta} - (v_{k1}^2 + v_{k2}^2 + ... + v_{k_{n-1}}^2)
\end{align}
You can pick all of the $v_{k1},\ ...,\ v_{k_{n-1}}$ freely, and then the final coordinate is determined by the above formula. This would produce a vector that must be in the set $V(v_0)$ by definition.